# Is it Possible to lock all routes except one, in vue-router ? Is it secure? Or maybe I should use another method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I want to build an online exam, this exam has 5 pages, there is a count down timer (120 seconds) and 4 questions on each page. After 120 seconds users are automatically transferred to the next page, or they can click on next button before that.

Laravel5.4 and VueJs, There is an Ajax request for every question that user answers. What I want is preventing the user from seeing other pages. Each page has to be visible for maximum 120 seconds. The user should not be able to click on back button and see previous pages.  Is this possible at all?

I want to create this app with `Vuejs` and `vue-router` but I don't know how to implement this with `vue-router`,  I have done some research but got not much result!

Or maybe I should not use `vue-router`, and use my own simple router, for example :

```
$("#page1").show();
$("#page2").hide();
$("#page3").hide();
.
.
// after 120 secs 
$("#page1").hide();
$("#page2").show();
$("#page3").hide();
.
.
 // i think this is not secure !
```

Any thoughts are appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
In this exam, user can see a list of  `English words` randomly selected from `words` table and nothing else! The user clicks on every word he thinks he knows its meaning! And an ajax request for every click to save the id of the word in `results` table. Also, There is a `fake_words` table that is 50 words randomly is selected in addition to `actual words` if the user clicks on fake words more than 3 times, the test will fail.  The final result will tell the user how much vocabulary skill he has.

**UPDATE 2:** I tried to do this with `vue-router`, but before starting to code, I thought maybe it should not be implemented with `vue-router` because all questions randomly get from DB in one query, then before exam starts, all of them are send (ajax) to the browser,  now what should I do? Slice them in separate arrays and send each array of questions to one of my pages? do I have to do that? can not I use only one `v-for` for them?   what if I decide to change number of questions?  Then I think I have to touch my code every time and create new page for `vue-router` or remove one of pages.

Comment: Quick question, are you using a Vue Component for this?

Comment: @TaylorFoster, yes I am using  Vue Component

Comment: The vue-router offers a programmatic navigation, including a `replace` method. Further more you  can add `meta` fields which you can access in `beforeEach` https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/meta.html. I&#39;m sorry but I cannot provide some example code since I am on my phone. However I cannot give you any insights from the security perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as security is concerned the choice of JS framework will have little impact if any. Vue.js is an excellent choice. Here is a sample code that will get you started:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="question" v-if="question">
      {{question}}
      <button @click="nextQuestion();" v-if="hasNextQuestion()"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        curQuestionNo: 0,
        maxQuestions: 4
        question: null,
        timer: null
      }
    },
    methods: {      
      fetchQuestion () {
        // return one question at a time from the server. Storing all questions on the client is not recommended.
        var url = 'https://myapi.com/question?curQuestionNo=' + this.curQuestionNo;

        axios.get(url) // or however you prefer to make ajax calls
          .then(res => {
            this.question = res.question;
            this.curQuestionNo++;
            this.stopTimer();
            if(this.hasNextQuestion()) {
              this.startTimer();
            }
          })
          .catch(() => {
            // do some error handling
          });
      },
      startTimer () {
        this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
          this.nextQuestion();
        }, 120 * 1000);
      },
      stopTimer () {
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
      },
      nextQuestion () {
        if(this.curQuestionNo > 0) {
          this.markAnswered(function() {  
            this.fetchQuestion();
          })
        } else {
          this.fetchQuestion();
        }
      },
      markAnswered (cb) {
        // record the answered question on server
        // server should only send the next question after this
        var url = 'https://myapi.com/mark-complete?curQuestionNo=' + this.curQuestionNo;

        axios.post(url) 
          .then(res => {
            this.fetchQuestion();
          })
          .catch(() => {
            // do some error handling
          });
      },
      hasNextQuestion () {
        return this.maxQuestions - (this.curQuestionNo + 1) > 0;
      }
    },
    created () {
      this.nextQuestion();      

    }
  }
</script>
```

On the server end, I recommend something like the following approach:

1. Send one question per request to the client
2. Ensure that the user has answered the previous question or the time frame allowed to answer the question has expired before the API returns the next question to the client. This can be achieved quite simply, just keep a counter in your data store to keep the record of the question number last answered (or expired) per user. The user should not be allowed to answer a question number equal or less than the number in the record. The server should only send the question number that is one greater than the number in the record.

Sample Code (not sure of Laravel 5 syntax but you should get the idea):

```
Route::get('question', function(){
    $curQuestionNo = intVal(Input::get('curQuestionNo'));
    $user = User::find($userId); // get the logged in user, for example
    if($user->current_question_number === $curQuestionNo) {
      $question = Question::where('question_no', $curQuestionNo + 1);
      $question->sent_at = time(); // store the time when the question was sent
      return $question
    } else {
      // deny access
    }
});

Route::post('mark-complete', function(){
    $curQuestionNo = intVal(Input::get('curQuestionNo'));
    $user = User::find($userId); // get the logged in user, for example
    $question = Question::find($curQuestionNo);
    if($question->sent_at > 120 seconds) {
     // do not record answers
    } else {
      // record answers
    }
    $user->current_question_number = $curQuestionNo;
    $user->save();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If this is really high risk code like an exam you should reconsider your approach: "[Never trust the client](https://www.google.nl/search?safe=off&rlz=1C1GGRV_enNL748NL748&q=never%20trust%20the%20client&oq=never%20trust%20the%20client&gs_l=serp.3..0.8532.8532.0.8957.1.1.0.0.0.0.75.75.1.1.0....0...1.1.64.serp..0.1.73.Fszaoxe7bk4)". I would suggest writing code for the backend to solve your issue.

1) Protect the endpoint with middleware, that:

2) creates a timestamp on visit of the page

3) Does not accept a new post (answer) from the user after 120 seconds

Note: I hope they have to answer online as well, otherwist it can't be secured: if the question is put in the browser window, they can cache thist question always, even with the best code they can take a picture of the screen.

**edit:** I would use [pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/pagination) to send the questions 1 by one with a time limit.

**edit 2:** I would also sent a notice to the server when the devtools are opened. You can try https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect

Comment: Thank you very much, yes I will protect my backend,  but it does not mean I should not use vuejs.  do you have any suggestion for how to implement this with vueJs?  I need this exam to be dynamic( number of pages and number of questions),  just a general pseudo code for using `v-for` or ... , for a simple auto page change! pagination and just hide other pages, I don't even know where to start!! Updated my question for more clarification to what I need

Comment: I would just [re-assign the window location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) everytime the timer runs out.

Comment: But I don't want  refresh on the page!

Comment: In that case ajax (xhr) is the only solution in which your students cannot simply (re-)show the previous question from their browsers

Comment: Don't re-assign window location, use router.replace: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html

Comment: Thanks @Cobaltway, very nice! I tried to do this, but before starting to code, I thought maybe it should not be implemented with `vue-router` because all questions randomly get from DB in one query, then before exam starts, all of them are send (ajax) to the browser,  now what should I do? Slice them in separate arrays and send each array of questions to one of my pages? do I have to do that? can not I use only one `v-for` for them?   what if I decide to change number of questions?  Then I think I have to touch my code every time and create new page for `vue-router` or remove one of pages.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this snippets will help:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        stepOne: 1,
    }
});

<step v-if="step==1"></step>

timeInterval = setInterval(function() {
    goToNextStep(2);
    this.$parent.stepOne = 0;
}.bind(this), 12000);
```